# How to fix running application error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want import this project from **Github** : [NotePad](https://github.com/farmerbb/Notepad).
But when running application on my phone, not running and show me this error : 
[image]

My android studio version is `2.1.3` and this version has lasted version! How can I fix this?

Comment: Do what it says: disable the Instant Run feature or update the Gradle plugin.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, how can fix this? can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do exactly what the message says. You have two choices:

1. Disable Instant Run by going to File -> Settings in the menu. In the search bar at the top right of the window, type "Instant Run" and press Enter. Now select the checkbox that disables Instant Run.
2. Update the Gradle plugin by opening `build.gradle` from the root directory of your project (not the one in the `app` module). Then find the line that has `compile com.android.tools.build:gradle:` followed by some version number. Change the version to `2.1.3`.

I suggest doing the later as you will then be less likely to run into other problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are miss understanding the error. Try updating the following in your gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}
```

Here is a reference to the compatibility [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility).

Comment: The version should be `2.1.3`. This is the version of the Android plugin for Gradle. On the other hand, `2.14.1` is the version of Gradle itself.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `build.gradle` and change this line

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
```

to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

It should work.

I'm already using this config with Andorid Studio 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Remove second and third line from dependencies and
Add this code

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile project(':NotePad')

}
```

It should work
Note that you have to provide path of NotePad project inside `compile project('')`